# usage of own data types Haskell receiving error: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Tags: haskell, types

To run a simulation I created my own data Type, so I can store the parameters.

```
        example:: Double -> SimuInfo -> Double
        example a information = 2* a * b
                              where
                                information{b = bFieldSaved }

        ...--Some other functions    

        data SimuInfo = Information {
                        massSaved:: Double
                        , chiSaved:: Double
                        , bFieldSaved :: Double
                        } deriving Show

        initialization:: Double -> Double -> Double -> SimuInfo
        initialization m chiInit b = Information{
                                  massSaved = m,
                                  chiSaved = chiInit,
                                  bFieldSaved = b
                                }
```

The problem is that, while trying to compile, I receive this error message. (the compiler says, that it is in the line where I have `...--Some other functions`)

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `where` clause doesn't look right - it should have a syntax like this:

```
where
  name = value
```

Perhaps you meant to write something like the following?

```
where
  b = bFieldSaved information
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pattern-match with record syntax, but you need to use the data constructor.

```
 example a (Information {bFieldSave = b}) = 2 * a * b
```

Also, your `initialization` function isn't really necessary, as
it is really equivalent to the data constructor you already have
underneath all the record syntax.

```
initialization:: Double -> Double -> Double -> SimuInfo
-- initialization m chiInit b = Information m chiInit b
initialization = Information
```